# Make output of source code blocks be inserted regardless of the exit status of the evaluation

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, c++

## The context

When evaluating the following code block, the output is not inserted in the `#+RESULTS` code block. This happens because of the `return 1` statement.

```
#+begin_src cpp :results output
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main()
try {
  throw std::runtime_error("A runtime error ocurred");
  return 0;
}
catch(std::runtime_error& e) {
  std::cout << "runtime_error: " << e.what() << '\n';
  return 1;
}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

If I replace `1` with `0`, then the output is indeed shown in the `#+RESULTS` code block

```
#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
runtime_error: A runtime error ocurred
#+end_example
```

## Additional context

Note that this behavior is also  present in `#+begin_src` whose language is `sh`. Here's a minimal working example: Evaluating the following code block would result in

```
#+begin_src sh
f() {
  return 1
}

printf "%s" "a"
f
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
```

If the return value of the `f` function is changed to `0`, then the output of the `printf` is shown

```
#+begin_src sh
f() {
  return 0
}

printf "%s" "a"
f
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_example
a
#+end_example
```

## The question

How can I make the output of the evaluated code block be inserted in its corresponding `#+RESULTS` code block regardless of the exit status of the evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, the Org documentation isn't very clear on the intended behavior here.  I'm looking at the [Results of Evalution](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Results-of-Evaluation) page.

But the workhorse function [org-babel-eval](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/src/aea1109ef735dd72db97b9255662b9ff5bcecfbc/lisp/ob-eval.el#L44) is clear in its docstring that results only come back if the command succeeds.  If the command fails, stdout is not returned and instead stderr is displayed in an error buffer.

`org-babel-eval` doesn't provide an easy way to change this behavior, so unfortunately I think the only way to get what you want right now is to redefine the function.  A change to the following code at the end of the function seems to work on my setup:

```
(if (or (not (numberp exit-code)) (> exit-code 0))
    (progn
      ... error processing stuff ...
      nil)  ; <-- replace nil with (buffer-string) and reevaluate the function
  (buffer-string)))))
```

I don't work with babel enough to have strong feelings about the code, but you might want to raise a thread on [the Org mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/emacs-orgmode) about your workflow and see if other folks would prefer this change as well.